# Bisecting egg shape curve

Tags: area

I have an egg shaped pill that I need to cut in half. assuming even distribution, mathematically speaking what would be the best way to half this pill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any plane of symmetry, then slicing along that axis does the trick.
(This works for a normal egg, which has an axis of rotational symmetry between the extreme points on the blunt and sharp ends.)

If there is no plane of symmetry but you can somehow determine the center of mass, then any plane through the center of mass works as well.